# Is it possible use MongoDB replace with BerkelyDB for OpenLDAP?

Tags: mongodb, openldap, berkeley-db

According to my daily work, we are using `BerkeleyDB (bdb)` + `OpenLDAP` for user authentication, but current I'm investigating the feasibility use `MongoDB` replace with `BerkeleyDB (bdb)`?

I know if possible I need to consider with data migration from `BerkeleyDB` to `MongoDB`, the old data must be changed to BSON format, but that's another problem.

The purpose is we need to have the faster data storage layer, any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with your current system? Why is it slow? What's your programming question?

Comment: I'm interested in the same problem for different reasons; I may have to build a website with Meteor, which by default uses MongoDB, and would want the OpenLDAP server to use the user data already in MongoDB instead of trying to keep two copies in sync.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to replace BerkeleyDB with MongoDB under OpenLDAP.

Comment: Nor would there be any good reason to. OpenLDAP's LMDB is smaller, faster, and more reliable than MongoDB. And orders of magnitude faster than BerkeleyDB, of course.